# Gutters GX and GY dont work for some reason in bootstrap, html/css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

i tried to add gutters to my grid with bootstrap, but they do not appear. i dont know why they dont as im following the steps as noted on the bootstrap docs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="container-sm text-center gy-6 gx-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="p-3 bg-success">1x12</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="p-3 bg-danger">1x6</div>    
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="p-3 bg-danger">2x6</div>    
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
           <div class="p-3 bg-warning">1x4</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="p-3 bg-warning">2x4</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="p-3 bg-warning">3x4</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
             <div class="p-3 bg-info">1x3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="p-3 bg-info">2x3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="p-3 bg-info">3x3</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="p-3 bg-info">4x3</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
             <div class="p-3 bg-success">1x2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="p-3 bg-success">2x2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="p-3 bg-success">3x2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="p-3 bg-success">4x2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="p-3 bg-success">5x2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="p-3 bg-success">6x2</div>
            </div>       
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
         <div class="p-3 bg-warning">1x2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="p-3 bg-warning">2x2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="p-3 bg-warning">3x2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="p-3 bg-warning">4x2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="p-3 bg-warning">5x2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="p-3 bg-warning">6x2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="p-3 bg-warning">1x2</div>
           </div>
           <div class="col">
             <div class="p-3 bg-warning">2x2</div>
           </div>
           <div class="col">
             <div class="p-3 bg-warning">3x2</div>
           </div>
           <div class="col">
             <div class="p-3 bg-warning">4x2</div>
           </div>
           <div class="col">
             <div class="p-3 bg-warning">5x2</div>
           </div>
           <div class="col">
             <div class="p-3 bg-warning">6x2</div>
           </div>              
        </div>
    </div>
      
</body>
</html>
```

And a screenshot of the current page i have.
Does anyone have an idea on what i am doing wrong?

Tried to add gutters with bootstrap using gy-6 and gx-6, tried multiple values. but didnt change the problem.

Comment: The examples under https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/gutters/ are adding the gx/gy classes on the `.row` elements - why are you placing them elsewhere?

Comment: This was just to try if that'd fix the problem so i still had them there, however, adding them on the row elements does not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with bootstrap, padding, gutters, and margin classes only go up to five, i.e. `.g-1`, `.g-2`, `.g-3`, `.g-4`, `.g-5`. Same with `p-1`, `p-2`, `p-3`, `p-4`, `p-5` and `m-1`, `m-2`, `m-3`, `m-4`, `m-5`.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 5 provides gutter values from 0 to 5. If you have created 6th gutter then only **g-6** can work.

To add extra gutter, please update **variables.scss** as below:

```
$grid-gutter-width: 1.5rem;
$gutters: (
  0: 0,
  1: $spacer * .25,
  2: $spacer * .5,
  3: $spacer,
  4: $spacer * 1.5,
  5: $spacer * 2,
  6: $spacer * 2.5,
);
```

Make sure you update numbers as per your requirements.

You can use gutter classes with flex elements like **row** class. So your code should be updated as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-sm text-center">
    <div class="row gy-6 gx-6">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="row gy-6 gx-6">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="row gy-6 gx-6">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="row gy-6 gx-6">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**You can also use "g-6" class in place of "gy-6 gx-6" classes**

Happy coding!!!